# How to count cells that includes non-empty characters in given range in Excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Simply, i want to count number of cells those are non-empty, which also means **excluded** cells that **only including whitespaces**, in a given range. I searched a lot but couldnt find any solution.

```
=COUNTIF(A1:A100;"<>"&"")
```

I have tried above formula but it only works for one possibility. I want to include other possibilities as well.

For example, lets say i have a some text like this in the range of A2:A100

```
A1: "Sometext 1"
A2: "Sometext 2"
A3: "Sometext 2"
A4: "Sometext 2"
A5: "Sometext 2"
A6: "Sometext 2"
A7: ""
.
.
.
.
A30: " "
A31: "     "
A32: "\n"
A33: "\t"
.
.
.
A100: " Some text 100"
```

And i dont want to count A7, A30, A31, A32, A33 and want to count rest of the cells.

EDIT: In the below image 1. is Google Sheet 2. is MS Excel 2016 I tried different formulas in both. But didnt work.

NOTE: In 1. characters inside the double quotes presents in the column A. It's been just visually demonstrated.

[image]

Comment: Make a new array =CLEAN(TRIM(A2:A100)) and then use it to look what you want for. Or try =SUM(N(CLEAN(TRIM(A2:A100))<>""))

Comment: Thanks but both didnt work

Comment: Should be A1:A100, not A2:A100. By didn't work what you mean? What cells were counted that should have not been?

Comment: Need more information. If the strings you show in `A32:A33` are literal, you will need a complex statement. If they are shorthand for `newline` and `tab`, then you can use `=COUNT(CODE(TRIM(CLEAN(A1:A100))))`. If some of your `whitespace` cells contain the `NBSP` or other non-printing characters, you will need to remove them specifically using the `SUBSTITUTE` function.

Comment: i've provided more information and ss. Those characters are just shorthand for whitespaces.

Comment: If in google sheets, wrap it in arrayformula: =arrayformula(SUM(N(CLEAN(TRIM(A1:A100))<>"")))  in Excel 2016 try Ctrl+Shift+Enter inside formula cell

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much. Now it worked.@user11222393 You can post the answer to the question and i'm gonna mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Excel* (if lower than *Excel 365*, <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in formula cell to make array formula):

```
=SUM(N(CLEAN(TRIM(A1:A100))<>""))
```

In *Google Sheets*:

```
=arrayformula(SUM(N(CLEAN(TRIM(A1:A100))<>"")))
```

`CLEAN` removes some of non printable characters. `TRIM` removes leading and trailing spaces (for strings like "     " will remove every space).